# Persistent access error calling a function returned by GetProcAddress

Tags: c++, loadlibrary, getprocaddress

Here is my code. It seems straighforward to do, but somehow it just isn't working.
The final call to the function always fails with an access error.

```
extern "C"
{
    typedef const char* (*Init_fptr_t)();

    HMODULE CMolNet::LoadDLL()
    {
       string dir = "C:\\MyDllDir\\";
       CA2W dirw( dir.c_str() );
       SetDllDirectory(dirw);

       string dllfile = CombinePath(dir.c_str(), "mydll.dll");
       CA2W dllfilew( dllfile.c_str() );

       mDLL = LoadLibraryEx(dllfilew,0,LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH);
       DWORD err = GetLastError();

       Init_fptr_t iFunc = (Init_fptr_t)GetProcAddress(mDLL,"Init");
       const char *res = (*iFunc)();
    }
}
```

mydll.dll is a third party dll. I do not have the source code, but the prototype of the function in the header is as follows:

```
extern "C" {
   const char* Init();
}
```

mydll.dll itself depends on several other dlls, stored in directory "C:\MyDllDir", hence the call to SetDllDirectory.

Some observations:

- I could not get vanilla LoadLibrary to work, but `LoadLibraryEx` with the arguments should seemed to work (in that `GetLastError` returns `0`)
- The address of the dll returned seems odd (`0x43900000`)
- The address of the function returned by `GetProcAddress` is also odd (`0x43902b34`), but reassuringly DLL Export Viewer reports the Init function as having an offset of `0x00002b34`)
- Calling the returned function always throws an access errors. I have tried every combination of `_ccdecl`, `__stdcall` etc on the `typedef` for the function but always get the same error. I have tried with and without `extern C`

Other data:

- This piece of c++ code is being called from a managed environment
- I am running on windows 7, 64 bit, but compiling the unmanaged part as win32

What am I doing wrong? How can I debug this? I have tried dependency walker and dll export viewer and everything seems ok.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is fine. You just don't need to use `*` when you're calling function through a pointer. Call it like ordinary function:

```
const char *res = iFunc();
```

instead of

```
const char *res = (*iFunc)();
```